# Can you define columns in sequelize with a period for storing in a postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

```
Module.init(
{
  "s.no": {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
},
```

Does wrapping it in double quotes work?
or should I just use sno?

Comment: What is "sno" mean?

Comment: @Anatoly Its just the name of the column

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL allows `.` to be a part of a column name it's just you always need to wrap it by double quotes to allow PostgreSQL to think it's not two parts of a path to some table.

Sequelize uses double quotes to wrap column names and generated column aliases in a result SQL query so feel free to try field names like `s.no`.